# Assigning new value to column rows based on another column's value

Tags: mysql, pandas

Sorry for the vague title - I couldn't figure out how to word it.

I have a dataframe containing data of a bike-sharing company. The relevant column rows for this question are start_station_name, start_lat and start_lng. The start_lat and start_lng values for each row differ slightly, so I want to assign each start_station_name a single unique value. The following code finds the average start_lat for each start station:

```
round(df.groupby('start_station_name')['start_lat'].mean(), 4)


2112 W Peterson Ave             41.9912
351                             41.9300
63rd St Beach                   41.7810
```

What I would like to do now is assign 41.9912 where the start_station_name is 2112 W Peterson Ave, 41.9300 to 351, etc..

Answer (score 0):

In your case do `transform`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('start_station_name')['start_lat'].transform('mean').round(4)
```